# Authorization API-key

Tags: c#

estoy tratando de conectarme a un API genere una key para la autorización he puesto esta en el código pero no funciona en que parte del código va esta key

**key = g1r5)JZ.L7e/s)hIN3W**

```
using RestSharp;
using System;

namespace Api
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://flet.fleet.com/api/v1/people/{{id}}");
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer {{API-key}}");
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Todas las APIs necesitan información diferente, ¿que API estas usando?

Comment: Servicios web, solo necesito saber donde se pone la key la he puesto por todo lado

Comment: ¿? Es difícil saberlo tal vez el método del WS lo necesita en el body, ¿Podemos ver la url de tu WS? Tal vez se especifica en el WSDL.

Comment: https://fleet.cloudfleet.com/api/v1/people/?

Comment: Usa el API-key generada en el header Authorization de la petición -> Authorization: Bearer {{API-key}}